How Can I Finish off this Solution on Ordinal Arithmetic (Cantor Normal Form)?
Question
Let $\beta = \omega + 3$, and $\alpha = \omega ^42+\omega ^34+6 = \beta ^\gamma \delta +\rho$. Find ordinals $\gamma$ and $\delta$, with $0<\delta<\beta$ and $\rho <\beta ^\gamma$.
Attempt
I don’t seem to have a way of doing this. Here is my attempt:
$\omega^42+\omega ^34+6 =(\omega +3)^2\omega^22+(\omega+3)^2\omega .4 +6= (\omega+3)^2(\omega ^22+\omega .4)+6$
Any hint on how to proceed will be appreciated.

Let's assume $\gamma < \beta$ (otherwise you need to consider cases involving epsilon numbers). Then, given that the leading term of $\beta^\gamma$ is $\omega^\gamma$, one deduces that $\gamma \le 4$. Since $\delta < \beta$ by assumption, hence $\delta \sim \omega^\eta$ with $\eta \le 1$, there are only two possibilites, namely $\gamma = 4$ with $\delta < \omega$ or $\gamma = 3$ with $\delta = \omega + n$, where $n = 0,1,2$.
You can show that $\beta^n = \omega^n + \omega^{n-1}3 + \ldots + \omega 3 + 3$ (see my answer to your previous question). In the case where $\gamma = 4$, the equation $\alpha = \beta^\gamma\delta + \rho$ is translated as
$$
\omega^4 2 + \omega^3 4 + 6 = (\omega^4 + \omega^3 3 + \omega^2 3 + \omega 3 + 3)\delta + \rho
$$
In consequence, one must have $\delta = 2$ in order to produce the correct leading term $\omega^4 2$, hence $(\omega^4 + \omega^3 3 + \omega^2 3 + \omega 3 + 3)\delta = \omega^42 + \omega^3 3 + \omega^2 3 + \omega 3 + 3$, which itself implies $\rho = \omega^3 + 6$. It is to be noted that one cannot choose $\delta = 1$, because it would necessitate $\rho = \omega^4 + \omega^3 4 + 6 > \beta^\gamma$.
If $\gamma = 3$, then one has :
$$
\beta^3\delta = (\omega^3 + \omega^2 3 + \omega 3 + 3)(\omega + n) = \omega^4 + \omega^3 n + \omega^2 3 + \omega 3 + 3,
$$
hence $\rho = \omega^3(4-n) + 6$, where the factor $(4-n)$ is a little abuse of notation for $m \le 4$ s.t. $n + m = 4$ in order to gather all the solutions together.
